# Find the earliest of a series of JavaScript dates

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, momentjs

How do I find the earliest of a set of dates. Currently I have the following code which works just fine:

```
var dates = [date1,date2]; // list of javascript dates 
var start = moment(new Date(9999, 0, 1))
// I wished this was one line in momentjs + underscorejs
_.forEach(dates, (date) => {
      if (moment(date).isBefore(start)) {
            start = moment(date);
      }
});
```

I was hoping there was a neater way (in one line). I would prefer to use a simpler function in Underscore (min does not work on dates) / momentjs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found _.min is reliable on `moment` instances. The following works:

```
    var dates = _.map([date1,date2],function(date){return moment(date)});
    var start = _.min(dates);
```

nevermind.

Comment: Remember you can also just pass in the function directly:
    `var dates = _.map([date1,date2],moment);`
    `var start = _.min(dates);`

Answer (score 4):

`var earliest = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, dates))`

see mdn [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

`Math.min(arg1,arg2,...argN)` finds the lowest of N numeric arguments.

Because of how `Function.prototype.apply` works, `Math.min.apply` takes two arguments, a
`this` setting, which appears to be unneeded here, and a `arg` `array`.

The numeric representation of a date is the ms since 1970.  A date coerced to a number will yield this value. A new date object is initialized to this lowest value, which is the same
date as the earliest date but not the same object.

This is similar to @fardjad's approach, but does not need the underscore.js library for _.min., and is shortened by the use of func.apply, which should be common javascript to most recent browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution :

```
var dates = [
    new Date(2010, 4, 10, 10, 07, 16),
    new Date(2010, 4, 8, 9, 16, 09),
    new Date(2010, 3, 30, 0, 15, 49),
    new Date(2010, 3, 8, 10, 08, 35)
];


var date_sort_asc = function (date1, date2) {

if (date1 > date2) return 1;
if (date1 < date2) return -1;
return 0;
};

var date_sort_desc = function (date1, date2) {

if (date1 > date2) return -1;
if (date1 < date2) return 1;
return 0;
};     

dates.sort(date_sort_asc);

document.write('<p>Dates sorted in ascending order (oldest to newest):</p>');
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
document.write(i + ': ' + dates[i] + '<br>');
}     

dates.sort(date_sort_desc);

document.write('<p>Dates sorted in descending order (newest to oldest):</p>');
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
document.write(i + ': ' + dates[i] + '<br>');

}
```

`dates[0]` would give you your first date in sorted format. Using the above you can sort in ascending and descending as well. Just need to alter at two places.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert dates to timestamps via `getTime()` and compare them:

```
// WARNING: Untested code ahead
function getMinDate(dates) {
    var timestamps = dates.map(function (date) { 
        return date.getTime() 
    });
    return new Date(_.min(timestamps));
}
```

Use it like

```
getMinDate(yourDatesArray); // returns min date
```

Comment: I believe that should be `var timestamps = $.map(dates, function (date) {`

Answer (score 2):

A dirty oneliner, which does not involve momentjs, could look like this:

```
var minDate = new Date(_.min(dates.map(function (date) { return date.getTime(); })));
```

Comment: hardly dirty :D